# XSSFWorkbook bold font not working

Tags: apache-poi

Code is as follows, is there something wrong with it?

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
Row row=sheet.createRow(0);

Font font= wb.createFont();
font.setBold(true);

CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setFont(font);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("hello你好");
cell.setCellStyle(style);
try {
    // Write the output to a file
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

I'm using Mac Numbers testing the generated excel file.

Note: The code abouve works when switch `XSSFWorkbook` to `HSSFWorkbook`.

Comment: What apache poi version? Your code works for me with apache poi 3.14. Maybe `font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);` will work with rather old versions?

Comment: @AxelRichter I use 3.14. After some experimenting, I find that mac numbers use <main:b val="1"/> for bold while the way xssf does is <main:b val="true"/> which mac numbers cannot recognize:(

Comment: **grmbl**. If Steve Jobs would know this. [Office Open XML specification: 3.8.2 b(Bold)](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf#page=2101&zoom=auto,51,464); [XML Schema boolean datatype](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
font.getCTFont().addNewB();
```

Found it here:
https://copyprogramming.com/howto/how-to-set-bold-font-using-the-latest-apache-poi