# Apache poi hyper link creation with https url

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have created a .xlsx file using Apache POI(3.17). One of the cell content is a URL. If the URL start with "https" then the cell is not clickable but if I replace "https" portion of the URL with "http" then the cell is clickable.

Can anyone have faced this issue?

Please see the code sample

```
import org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.HyperlinkType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Hyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class WriteExcelBasic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String excelFileName = "/Users/UserHome/Test3.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);


        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet");


        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);


            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);


                Hyperlink link = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
                String ss = "https://news.google.com/news/headlines?ned=us&hl=en";
                link.setAddress(ss);
                cell.setHyperlink(link);
                cell.setCellValue(ss);



            }
        }

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            wb.write(baos);
            byte[] myByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            fos.write(myByteArray);
            fos.flush();
        }
        finally {
            wb.close();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without some code-sample showing what exactly you did try already it is very hard to tell...

Comment: Sorry for not providing any code earlier. Updated the question with the code sample.Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, for me both types of cell are clickable as expected... Can you try the same resulting file on another machine?

Comment: May be it's related to Xls application. It worked fine in LibreOffice but it does not work in Numbers (mac os default) application.  As far as I remember correctly it did not work in Microsoft excel but I need to recheck it.

Comment: On a recheck I found that it's working with MS excel. Therefore it have only issue with Numbers (mac os default) application.

Comment: Since it's very difficult to check why it's not working on a particular application I would like to close this question. Thanks evryone

Comment: Sounds like this could be a bug in Numbers, but there's a few more steps before that conclusion can be made. Are you able to create a workbook in Numbers with a clickable https hyperlink? If so, if you unzip the xlsx workbook and inspect the xml file contents, how does it compare to the file that Apache POI produced? What happens if that file is created by Excel or LibreOffice? Is the link clickable in Numbers and are there differences in the zipped xml files that would explain why Numbers doesn't make the hyperlink clickable?

Comment: Just for an update Numbers have the same issue for font style https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583593/xssfworkbook-bold-font-not-working ( even I faced the same issue).