# How to set bold font using the latest apache poi?

Tags: apache-poi

I used the latest apache poi

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

but I cannot set bold font, below code does not work

```
font.setBold(true);
```

because the default it true

```
set a boolean value for the boldness to use. If omitted, the default value is true.
```

and does not exist `setBoldWeight` method either

So how can I set bold weight in the latest apache poi?

---

code

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
XSSFCell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("hello world");

XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
font.setBold(true);
cellStyle.setFont(font);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("bold_test.xls")) {
    wb.write(fos);
}
```

effect

[image]

and the bold effect should like this

[image]

Comment: [Font.setBold(true)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#setBold-boolean-) should work fine - what isn't working for you?

Comment: @Gagravarr because: `set a boolean value for the boldness to use. If omitted, the default value is true.`

Comment: So you have not even tried it already? The "If omitted, the default value is true." is confusing. The `setBold(true)` sets the `Font` to be bold. Of course `setBold(false)` also is possible to explicit set the `Font` to be not bold. And if not `setBold(true)` was used, the `Font` is **not** bold per default at all.

Comment: Of course I had tried

Comment: Then please show [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the behavior how `Font.setBold` does not work.

Comment: please see my supplementary

Comment: Not reproducible for me. Exact your code works for me and the cell A1 is set bold. Of course I had to change the file name since you are creating `XSSFWorkbook` but do saving it as `bold_test.xls`. The name should be `bold_test.xlsx` for `XSSFWorkbook`.

Comment: @Axel Richter  Thanks Maybe only in Mac Numbers the bold effect cannot work. I sent the file to my colleague and open it using ms office excel, it does not have this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mac Numbers does not interpret `<b val="true"/>` correctly. But this violates the specification. See [xmlschema-2 boolean](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean): "An instance of a datatype that is defined as ·boolean· can have the following legal literals {true, false, 1, 0}. ".

But it will interpret `<b />` correctly. This also is valid to flag a `Font` to be bold. And this also is meant with "If omitted, the default value is true.". If the `b` tag is there but does not have a value, neither `true` nor `false`, then it defaults to `true`. To set not bold either the `b` tag must be removed or must be set `<b val="false"/>` or `<b val="0"/>`. There `apache poi` does the best, most compatible. It removes the `b` tag.

Same is for `i`talic and `s`trikeout.

Hint for `apache poi`developer team: Consider setting  `<b />`, `<i />` and `<s />` without values to set `true`. This will be the most compatible.

Try:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateExcelFontBold {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
  XSSFCell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("hello world");

  XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
  XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
  //font.setBold(true); // <b val="true"/> does not work using Mac Numbers
  font.getCTFont().addNewB(); // maybe <b /> will work?
  cellStyle.setFont(font);
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

  try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("bold_test.xlsx")) {
   wb.write(fos);
  }

 }

}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right `font.getCTFont().addNewB()` works in Mac Numbers.

Comment: but the javadoc: ` If omitted, the default value is true.` still misleading.  It's easy to misunderstand do not need set bold true explicitly.

Comment: @zhuguowei:See my supplement for what really is meant with: "If omitted, the default value is true.".

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the Mac Numbers bug

Comment: Yes there was a déjà vu now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583593/xssfworkbook-bold-font-not-working.